Custom URL button on record page redirecting to URL addressable LWC not working on mobile
I have a lightning web component URL Addressable:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__UrlAddressable</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

This is the javascript handling the received record id:
_oppId;
set oppId(value){
    this._oppId = value;
    this.init();
}

get oppId(){
    return this._oppId;
}

@wire(CurrentPageReference)
getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
    if (currentPageReference) {
        this.oppId = currentPageReference.state.c__oppId;
    }
}

The init() method makes an Apex call.
I defined a custom URL button on the Opportunity record page, with the following URL:
/lightning/cmp/c__nuevaVersionChecklist?c__oppId={!Opportunity.Id}

This works like charm on desktop, but when accessing on Mobile, I get a no rows query exception, clearly stating that the c__oppId param is not sending the id correctly through the URL.
Is there something I'm missing? I used a custom URL button because LWC record actions are not supported on Mobile. Any help is appreciated.

Have you checked this? -https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_UrlAddressable.htm&release=250&type=5
